# Code behind for print?

Tags: vb.net, printing, report

I have a report that I need to print after a sale has completed.

I am having issues with the length and printing when using PrintForm and PrintDocument components however if I right click and select Print from the list the report prints perfectly.

Is there any way that I could write code in my form load event that would imitate the right click print?

Ive been struggling with this part of my project for ages now and the whole thing is now way behind schedule.

My Code for the whole Receipt form page is:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class Receipt
Public PicLocation As String
Dim Ctrl1, Ctrl2 As Control
Dim CN As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim CMD As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim DataR As OleDb.OleDbDataReader

'To display into datagrid purpose
Dim dataS As New DataSet
Dim dataAd As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Public SqlStr, SqlStr1, DBPath, DBStatus, SearchBox As String
Dim X, Y, SqlH, Onh As Integer
Dim SqlUser As String
Dim DataP As Decimal
Dim Balance As Integer

Private Sub Receipt_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ProductListDataSet' table.
    DBPath = (Application.StartupPath & "\ProductList.accdb")
    If CN.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        CN.Close()
        DBStatus = ("Not Connected")
    End If
    SqlStr = ("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =" & DBPath)
    CN.ConnectionString = SqlStr
    CN.Open()
    Onh = Nothing

    lblTime.Text = DateAndTime.Now
    lblUser.Text = Login.userTB.Text

    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT * Receipt"
    Me.ReceiptTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = True
    Me.ReceiptTableAdapter.Connection = CN
    Me.ReceiptTableAdapter.Connection.CreateCommand.CommandText = sql
    Me.ReceiptTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProductListDataSet.Receipt)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    Me.Refresh()


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    With Me.PrintForm1
        .PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPrinter

        Dim MyMargins As New Margins
        With MyMargins
            .Left = 0
            .Right = 0
            .Top = 0
            .Bottom = 0
        End With
        .PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = MyMargins
        .Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.CompatibleModeClientAreaOnly)

    End With

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: "I am having issues with the length and printing when using PrintForm and PrintDocument" - what issues are you having? You need to be more specific- also Post some code so we can see what you have done so far.

Comment: Print form doesnt print the whole receipt, if a part of it is not shown and a scroll bar is there it doesnt print the part that is scrolled out even when I use the scrollable action.

My code:
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

With Me.PrintForm1
.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPrinter

Dim MyMargins As New Margins
With MyMargins
.Left = 0
.Right = 0
.Top = 0
.Bottom = 0
End With
.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = MyMargins
.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.Scrollable)

End With